# execute terminal from c program

Tags: c, bash, terminal, system, exec

To run a c program you do something like this

```
bash> gcc test.c -o test
```

and then

```
bash> ./test
```

How can i do to make test.c execute a terminal in another window??

Comment: What do you mean? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

**xterm -e "./test"**

This will execute 'test' in a new xterm window.  Assuming Linux of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can fork a new process and use system() function. This will work on most of  Linux distributions. Just check the terminal properties to know the command to execute a new terminal. "gnome-terminal" works for me(Ubuntu, Redhat).

```
int main()
{
        if(!fork())// child process
        system("gnome-terminal");
        else
        {
                //do rest of the things here in parent process......
        }

}
```

After fork(), a new terminal window will open as a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which system you're on and which terminal you have in mind, but here's how to do it if you're on gnome (ubuntu for instance)

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./test"
```

If you don't want the window to close immediately after `./test` finishes, you do

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./test; cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a window for a new terminal, or what do you want to do?
Your question isn't really clear.

If you want to run some commands, you need to cope with sys calls to launch a new process.

On Windows there's the system() function, but I'm not sure it exists on Linux or other posix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use of the word `terminal` im guessing you are using osx.

You can use applescript to get the behavior:

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
do script with command "cd _directory_; ./test"
end tell
```

If you want the program to launch a window, have the program call popen to launch the command [or write to a temporary file and launch the script]